# IBM Cloud AppID: Application role doesn't returns in JWT

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

In my backend service, I require a token that contains the "roles" claim in the client credentials flow. So I've tried to setup App ID as described in the article about [Assigning roles to an application](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-access-control&interface=api#assign-roles-app), unfortunately, I didn't succeed in this.

Steps were done for setup:

1. Register the application with a "regular web application" type
2. Create a role
3. Assing role to the application like described in docs
4. Extend token config with
   "accessTokenClaims": [
   {
   "source": "roles"
   }
   ]
5. Retrieve token for by Postman

Used parameters:

- URL: [https://eu-de.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/{tenantid}/token](https://eu-de.appid.cloud.ibm.com/oauth/v4/%7Btenantid%7D/token)
- Body: form data and form data encoded(tried both)
- grant type: client_credentials;
- Basic auth: username: client_id; password: client_secret

I also tried to use the body with form data and form data encoded(tried both)

- grant type: client_credentials;
- client_id: client_id
- client_secret: client_secret

Comment: What is your question? Any errors?

Comment: @data_henrik role claim should return, but it doesn't. So my question is, is there some step I missed or anything else?

Comment: I am missing details in your question. Could you share how you map the roles (input name, output name)? I have that working and use the roles as part of federated identities in IBM Cloud. The code is here https://github.com/data-henrik/cloud-project-onboarding-terraform/tree/workshop_hackathon

Comment: Simple role created in App ID UI: Profiles and roles -> Roles -> Create Role. Further, I've just attached the role to the application by IBM Management API as described in the docs
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-access-control&interface=api#assign-roles-app
What grant type you're using for token retrieving?

Comment: Add details to your question. How is the mapping done (https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-customizing-tokens#custom-claims-mapping)?

Comment: Oh, that's what you mean. This is described in question "Extend token config with "accessTokenClaims": [ { "source": "roles" } ]". That's all how I changed the token config.

Comment: See the linked code, as mentioned. https://github.com/data-henrik/cloud-project-onboarding-terraform/blob/workshop_hackathon/terraform/01-appid/main.tf#L81

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help

Comment: Please add details to your question. The more, the better. Else it remains guesswork

Comment: The documentation https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-access-control&interface=ui#role-tokens says "By default, roles are not returned in a users token. It is recommended that your runtime decisions are configured based on scopes. But, if you would like to use roles, you can map them to your tokens by using custom claims mapping."  The procedure is documented at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/appid?topic=appid-customizing-tokens but I have not tried it.